# New object from type? Specifically a resx file. I want a different resx at runtime

Tags: c#, resources, resx, activator, system.type

I'm trying to use browser specific resx files in some automation tests.  I'm stuck at the point where I wish to instansiate the type.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have tried activator.createInstance etc... with no luck.

```
 public class WebAiiBaseTest : BaseTest
{
    private readonly IDictionary<BrowserType, Type> resxMapper = new Dictionary<BrowserType, Type>{
                                                                {BrowserType.Chrome, typeof(Chrome)}
                                                                , {BrowserType.Safari, typeof(Safari)}
                                                                , {BrowserType.FireFox, typeof(Firefox)}
                                                                , {BrowserType.InternetExplorer, typeof(InternetExplorer)}
                                                            };



    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        Initialize();
        Launcher.LaunchRepairInformation();

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TestCleanUp()
    {
        Launcher.NavigateToRepairInformation();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureCleanup()
    {
        CleanUp();
    }

    protected object BrowserResx
    {
        get { return Activator.CreateInstance(resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]); }

    } 


}
```

This code returns an instance, but it is of type object. I would like to return a strongly typed instance.  I have tried the generic overload for CreateInstance, like this

```
return Activator.CreateInstance<resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]>();
```

but Visual Studio does not like this syntax. What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any tips or advice.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: do the browsertypes have a baseclass?

Comment: no, it's an enum. Base on the current value, I want to instansiate the correct type of resx file.

Comment: The return type of Activator.CreateInstance (as well as your method) is object, so if that's not what you wnat, you need to cast it to something. Perhaps the method should be a generic?

Comment: Oh never mind - what @rene said, if you want to return a strongly-typed instance, then that necessitates having a base class that the browser types inherit, which should be your return type. Otherwise, your code would need to know the specific type at compile time and the method doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't what to return an instance of BrowserType, I want to return an instance of type from the dictionary based on the BrowserType enum.

Comment: What is "an instance of type"? A type is a signature for an object, an instance of a type is a BrowserType. If you want to return a type, then  just: `return resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]`

Comment: @jamietre I get what I ask for... @Hcabnettel I mean the classes Safari, Firefox, Chrome, InternetExplorer do they have a base class? If they don't do they have common methods/properties/events? if yes, extract those, move them to an abstract class, subclass your safari, Firefox etc from that base class and cast the result from Activator.CreateInstance to your baseclass.

Comment: @rene, my shorthand may not have been clear, i was just agreeing with you.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not correctly spelled, did you try

`return Activator.CreateInstance(resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]);` ?

Comment: yes, of course. See the first implementation.  It works but it returns type object. I would like a strongly typed object returned.

Comment: I doubt you can achieve what you are looking for, at least, you will have to create a method for each browser type as they will return different type of objects. one solution is to not embed resources in assembly and use ResourceManager to load different resources for different browsers. take a look http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Saveandloadimagefromresourcefile.htm <-- here

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not getting exactly what you're trying to do but here are the only things I can think of, I'm not sure the comment thread is getting any more clear.

```
public interface IBrowser
{
}
public class Chrome: IBrowser
{
}
... 

protected IBrowser BrowserResx
{
    get { return (IBrowser)Activator.CreateInstance(resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]); }

}
```

Alternatively:

```
protected T BrowserResx<T> where T: IBrowser
{
        get { return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(resxMapper[ActiveBrowser.BrowserType]); }
}
```

.. if your class was designed as a generic. If there's no base class for the browser types, or interface, then there's no way to return something more strongly typed: they only share "object" in common.